# Performance of break in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I did a exercise in Leetcode, the problem is shown below:

> Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index if the
>   target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were
>   inserted in order.
>
> You may assume no duplicates in the array.
>
> Here are few examples.
>
> ```
> [1,3,5,6], 5 → 2
> [1,3,5,6], 2 → 1
> [1,3,5,6], 7 → 4
> [1,3,5,6], 0 → 0
> ```

This is my first try

```
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {

    if(nums.length === 0){
        return -1;
    }

    var greaterThanPrev = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] === target){
            return i;
        }else if(nums[i] < target){
            greaterThanPrev = true;   
        }else{
            if(greaterThanPrev){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!greaterThanPrev){
        return 0
    }else{
        return nums.length
    }
}
```

Then I think there is no need to iterate all elements in array if the target is greater than current element, so I add a break in the if clause.

```
var searchInsert = function(nums, target) {
    if(nums.length === 0){
        return -1;
    }

    var greaterThanPrev = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] === target){
            return i;
        }else if(nums[i] < target){
            greaterThanPrev = true;   
        }else{
            if(greaterThanPrev){
                return i;
            }else{
               //add this break to avoid iterate all elements in array
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!greaterThanPrev){
        return 0
    }else{
        return nums.length
    }

};
```

IMO, second solution should be faster than first one, but according by results, the first one is always like 95ms and the solution with `break` is always more than 120 ms.

Is there any performance issue with keyword `break` in javascipt?

Comment: The second one is not O(log n). [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) would be O(log n).

Comment: @Ryan Even if the second is not n(logn), it should take less time than the first one. Because it will not always iterate all elements in array like first one, right?

Comment: It'll iterate all elements only in exactly one case, when the target number is smaller than all the elements in the array. In all other cases it just adds overhead.

Comment: And in that case you could just `return 0` instead of breaking the loop.

Comment: Break does not mean log(n). Don't make this kind of assumption the day of the exam :-P

Comment: Since it's sorted, try out a `binary search` implementation. If it's Leetcode and sorted list, you have to try it :)

Comment: There is no obvious answer to your (interesting) question. If there is actually a drop of performance - I'm curious to know how you mesure it though - I don't believe that `break` is responsible. I would rather look at the `else` statement since it can be translated to a comparison by the parser. However, if you want an accurate answer, I'm afraid that you'll have to read the specifications of the language :-(

Comment: @procrastinator Yes, I agree with you. I measured it by time reported by Leetcode. But I find that is not accurate because it varies a lot every time I submit. So I don't think there is a performance drop in break for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether it breaks or returns early, I would consider any for loop iterating through an array of numbers O(n). Big O focuses on worst-case analysis and it would be a best-case scenario if the target were less than, or was the first element in the numbers array. This implementation is more minimalistic but also returns early in the for-loop where possible.

```
function searchInsert(numbers, target) {

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == target) {
            return i;
        } else if (numbers[i] > target) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return numbers.length || -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be zero when length is 0. -1 is supposed to be returned when the array is null. And thank you for explaining definition of big O.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought there may be a rule you were abiding by, and no problem, you're welcome.